# Transperent background in JFrame bug

Tags: java, swing, jframe, paint

I am making a simple Java program. Now it just makes an 8x8 checkers field. But when start my program background of my JFrame like makes a photo of my screen and it doesn't change. However, I set it to be white. Is it a problem with the code or something else is wrong?

I set the background to be white and didn't set it at all. Neither helped.

```
package mainpackage;

import com.sun.prism.paint.*;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.io.File;

class Field extends JFrame {

    Field() //little constructor with no arguments
    {
        this(800, 800);
    }

    Field(int a, int b) //the most big constructor
    {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBackground(Color.white);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        setResizable(false);

        setSize(a, b);
    }

    void makeVisible() //making frame visible
    {
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void makeInvisible() //making frame invisible
    {
        setVisible(false);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) //painting the board
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < 10; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {

                g.setColor(getCurrentColor(x,y)); // get and set color of current square
                {
                    if (x % 2 == 0) // if x even
                    {
                        if (y % 2 == 0) {
                            g.setColor(Color.lightGray); // if x even y even make gray
                        } else {
                            g.setColor(Color.pink); // if x even and y odd make pink
                        }
                    } else { // if odd even
                        if (y % 2 == 0) {
                            g.setColor(Color.pink); // if x odd and y even make pink
                        } else {
                            g.setColor(Color.lightGray); // if x odd and y odd make gray
                        }
                    }
                }
                if(x>0&&x<9&&y>0&&y<9) { // only if 0 < x < 9 and 0 < y < 9
                    g.fillRect(50 + 60 * x, 50 + 60 * y, 60, 60); // fill current rectangle
                }
                else if(y==0&&x>0&&x<9)
                {

                    g.setColor(Color.black);
                    g.drawString(Integer.toString(x),50 + 60 * x, 50 + 60 * y);
                }
              /*  if (y == 2&& x== 1) {
                   *//* JLabel label = new JLabel();
                    label.setLocation(x*60, y*60);
                    label.setSize(60, 60);
                    label.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
                    label.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:/Users/Asus/Desktop/My Work/checkers/res/images/checkerimage.png"));
                    add(label);*//*
                }*/
            }
        }

    }
    private Color getCurrentColor(int x, int y) //set the color of current square
    {
        if (x % 2 == 0) // if x even
        {
            if (y % 2 == 0) {
                return Color.red;
            } else {
                return Color.blue;// if x even and y odd make blue
            }
        } else { // if odd even
            if (y % 2 == 0) {
                return Color.blue; // if x odd and y even make blue
            } else {
                return Color.red; // if x odd and y odd make red
            }
        }
    }

}

package mainpackage;

public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Field f1 = new Field();
        f1.makeVisible();

    }
}
```

[Picture of the programm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/liYhL.png)

[The second picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FR9hb.png)

Comment: You shouldn't be overriding `paint` of `JFrame`, it's a composite component, meaning there are a number of component already on the frame which can interfere with the painting process, also, you MUST call the paints super method, unless you're prepared to over all of its responsibility

Comment: Simply add super.paint(g); after ' public void paint(Graphics g) //painting the board
    {'? Looks like it really helped me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by have a read through [Painting in AWT and Swing](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for a better understanding of how painting works in Swing and how you should work with it.

Two basic issues:

1. Overriding paint of `JFrame`
2. Breaking the paint chain (failing to call the `paint` method's `super` method)

`JFrame` is a composite component, that is, it has a number of components already added it that makes up its functionality, which can interfere with the what ever is painted through `paint`.

[image: Lots of stuff here]

Painting is a complex process, involving a number of steps, delegated through a series of sub methods.  Unless you want to take over ALL the responsibility, you should call `super.paintXxx` before you perform any custom painting.

So, what's the answer?  Two fold...

- User `JPanel` instead of a `JFrame` as a bases for your component
- Override `paintComponent` instead of `paint` (and call `super.paintComponent` before you do any custom painting)

For example...

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.RED);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new Field());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class Field extends JPanel {

        public Field() {
            setOpaque(false);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(800, 600);
        }

        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            for (int y = 0; y < 10; y++) {
                for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {

                    g2d.setColor(getCurrentColor(x, y)); // get and set color of current square
                    {
                        if (x % 2 == 0) // if x even
                        {
                            if (y % 2 == 0) {
                                g2d.setColor(Color.lightGray); // if x even y even make gray
                            } else {
                                g2d.setColor(Color.pink); // if x even and y odd make pink
                            }
                        } else { // if odd even
                            if (y % 2 == 0) {
                                g2d.setColor(Color.pink); // if x odd and y even make pink
                            } else {
                                g2d.setColor(Color.lightGray); // if x odd and y odd make gray
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if (x > 0 && x < 9 && y > 0 && y < 9) { // only if 0 < x < 9 and 0 < y < 9
                        g2d.fillRect(50 + 60 * x, 50 + 60 * y, 60, 60); // fill current rectangle
                    } else if (y == 0 && x > 0 && x < 9) {

                        g2d.setColor(Color.black);
                        g2d.drawString(Integer.toString(x), 50 + 60 * x, 50 + 60 * y);
                    }
                    /*  if (y == 2&& x== 1) {
                     *//* JLabel label = new JLabel();
                                        label.setLocation(x*60, y*60);
                                        label.setSize(60, 60);
                                        label.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
                                        label.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:/Users/Asus/Desktop/My Work/checkers/res/images/checkerimage.png"));
                                        add(label);*//*
                                }*/
                }
            }
            g2d.dispose();
        }

        private Color getCurrentColor(int x, int y) //set the color of current square
        {
            if (x % 2 == 0) // if x even
            {
                if (y % 2 == 0) {
                    return Color.red;
                } else {
                    return Color.blue;// if x even and y odd make blue
                }
            } else { // if odd even
                if (y % 2 == 0) {
                    return Color.blue; // if x odd and y even make blue
                } else {
                    return Color.red; // if x odd and y odd make red
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

If you really want a transparent window, then you should look at [How to Create Translucent and Shaped Windows](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/trans_shaped_windows.html)